# How to get images size fixed in php?

Tags: php

**How do I get images in certain fixed size, example I've attached the image and codes for your review**

[Please click on this link (image) to understand my question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIzz0.png)

```
 <img src="<?php echo $picfile; ?>" border="0" width="<?php echo $imgsize[0]; ?>" height="<?php echo $imgsize[1]; ?>" align="left" style="border:1px solid black;margin-right:5px;">
```

Comment: well you could use GD to crop the image, or you could use a combination of html/css to do what you are describing.

Comment: Have a look at [getimagesize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php)

Comment: It looks like he is already doing that in the code sample he added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get image details with

```
$details = get_image_size($filename).
```

$details[3] will contain the width and height in html format ready for you to  use.

Comment: It looks like he is already doing that in the code example he added.

Answer (score 1):

Could possibly try this

```
img src='$filename' style='width:250px; height: 250px'
```

allows you to strech image to specific size

to scale you could use

```
img src='$filename' style='width:auto; height: 250px'
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this. As you are looping through your images, you want to keep track of the maximum width.

```
$newImageArray = array();
$maxWidth = 0;
$maxHeight = 0;
$i = 0;
forEach ( $imageArray as $picfile ) {
    $newImageArray[$i]['picFile'] = $picfile;
    $imgsize = get_image_size($picfile);
    $newImageArray[$i]['width'] = $imgsize[0];
    if ( $imgsize[0] > $maxWidth ) {
        $maxWidth = $imgsize[0];
    }
    $newImageArray[$i]['height'] = $imgsize[1];
    if ( $imgsize[1] > $maxHeight ) {
        $maxHeight = $imgsize[1];
    }
    $1++;
}
forEach ( $newImageArray as $i) { ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $picfile; ?>" border="0" width="<?php echo $maxWidth; ?>" height="<?php echo $maxHeight; ?>" align="left" style="border:1px solid black;margin-right:5px;">
<?php
}
```

Now you shouldn't really be doing this. A CSS based option would work better. You can add a wrapper container with a width on it and set the images to display:block;width:100%; and the images will always fill the space. I will edit with that solution shortly.

This will keep the image within a fixed width, and scale the image to fit inside of the box when it is too large.

HTML:

```
<div class="imgWrap">
   <img src="http://www.captainangry.com/img/1236647133510anonib.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.imgWrap {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
}
.imgWrap img {
    display:block;
    max-width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do any work in PHP then just wrap the image in a div and set `overflow:hidden`. This assumes that you know the height you want all of your images to be.

```
<div style="width:<?php echo $imgsize[0]; ?>; height:100px; overflow:hidden; border:1px solid black; margin-right:5px">
    <img src="<?php echo $picfile; ?>" width="<?php echo $imgsize[0]; ?>" height="<?php echo $imgsize[1]; ?>">
</div>
```